# "Multi-Award-Winning" or "Multi-Award Winning"?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Which one is the correct use?

I know that "award-winning" uses a hyphen and that "multi" needs a hyphen, but I'm not sure if the hyphen gets a double or single use in "multi-award-winning/multi-award winning".

Comment: I checked the Google Ngram, and it showed none of the results of multi-award-wining. I think the second one, multi-award winning is the correct one.

Comment: What's the grammar part of this question? Seems to be about writing to me.

Comment: Just "Award-winning" does not exclude several awards, and perhaps as an announcement [*less is more*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/less+is+more).

Comment: I'd like to keep the "Multi-" in the beginning.

Comment: Would the full context not make it clear that "Multi-Award" describes not (the successful thing) but only the "Winning" of it? By contrast, "Multi-Award-Winning" describes (the successful thing).

Answer (score -4):

https://www.quora.com/Is-multi-award-winning-hyphenated.

The answer with explanation can be found in the above link.

Comment: Link only answers are viewed as poor quality because they become useless if the link "rots".

Comment: A bare link is never an adequate answer. Can you summarize what the link says? Also, make sure to credit the author.

Comment: Using Quora for a definitive and authoritative answer is a little thin. Standards here are high; there, less so. My answers there offer the voice of reason, but only as my opinion. No hard feelings.